# Left join on two tables with different conditions on part of table data

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I want to join two tables using left join. I want to put one condition one part  of the data and another condition on rest of the data. It's confusing , let me explain with an example:

```
Table  - a
 Date        ID    name
2015-04-30  Y235J   P54
2015-04-30  Y237F   P54
2015-04-30  Y234A   P54
2015-04-30  Y235    P54
2015-04-30  Y239    P54
2015-04-30  Y297    P54
2015-04-30  L234    P54
2015-04-30  L236    P54
2015-04-30  M234    P54
2015-04-30  M237    P54
2015-04-30  M239    P54
2015-04-30  M238    P54
2015-05-31      
2015-06-30      
2015-07-31      
2015-08-31      
2015-09-30      
2015-10-31      

Table -b

Date1        ID1 
2015-04-30  Y235
2015-04-30  Y239
2015-04-30  L234
2015-04-30  M237
2015-04-30  M239
2015-05-31  B435
2015-05-31  B486
2015-06-30  B435
2015-06-30  B486
2015-06-30  B477
2015-07-31  G456
2015-07-31  G345
2015-07-31  B486
2015-07-31  B477
```

I want to do left join table a with table b. I want to put conditions that table a **left joins** with table b based on **Date and ID if Date1 <= '2015-04-30'** and based on **just Date if Date1 > '2015-04-30'**

Can you please tell how to deal with this situation

```
    Select * from a left joins b (If b.Date1 <= '2015-04-30' then on 
a.Date = b.Date1 and a.ID = b.ID else on a.Date = b.Date1)
```

I am not able to get answer for it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express this condition as:

```
Select *
from a left join
     b 
     on a.Date = b.Date1 and
        (b.Date1 > '2015-04-30' or  and a.ID = b.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks Gorden!! it worked.. you are the savior... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from a 
left join b
on a.ID = b.ID
and a.Date = b.Date1
where b.Date1 > '2015-04-30';
```

Comment: I think this will join first based on two conditions and then put the where condition on it.